# Ho to find the Derivative of $e(x, t) = \frac{1}{S(x, t)} \int_x^\infty S(y, t) \;\mathsf{d}y $ with respect to $t$

Tags: calculus

#### My problem

I am trying to find the time derivative (i.e. with respect to $t$) of the function

$$ e(x, t) = \frac{1}{S(x, t)} \int_x^\infty S(y, t) \;\mathsf{d}y $$

and show, given that $S(0) = 1$, that

$$ \dot{e}(0, t) = \int_0^\infty \dot{S}(y, t) \;\mathsf{d}y $$

where I use the dot notation for the time derivative.

##### My approach

Defining $f(x) = \frac{1}{S(x, t)}$, $g(x) = \int_x^\infty S(y, t) \;\mathsf{d}y$ and applying the product rule, I get

$$\dot{e}(x, t)  = - \frac{\dot{S}(x, t)}{S(x,t)^2} \int_x^\infty S(y, t) \;\mathsf{d}y + \frac{1}{S(x, t)} \int_x^\infty \dot{S}(y, t) \;\mathsf{d}y$$

Cross-checking with Wolframalpha did only yield the left part before the plus sign ([see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=d%2Fdt%20%201%2FS%28x%2Ct%29%20%20int_x%5E%5Cinfty%20S%28y%2C%20t%29%20dy)). Hence I am not sure if I am correct. I would be happy if anyone could confirm my derivations / find my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have differentiated correctly. It seems as though Wolfram interprets your query as

$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{1}{S(x,t)}\right)\int_{x}^{\infty}S(y,t) \ dy.$$

If you use the "math input" tool you will get [the correct answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Partial%5BDivide%5B1%2CS%5C%2840%29x%5C%2844%29t%5C%2841%29%5DIntegrate%5BS%5C%2840%29y%5C%2844%29t%5C%2841%29%2C%7By%2Cx%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D%2Ct%5D).

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!